# Is it possible to repeatedly use the same text box to get input from users in HTML & Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox

So I have a created a text box using html code along with a button for "confirm"

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" style="height: 10px; width: 50px" value="">

<button onclick="enter_value()">Confirm</button>
```

What I intend to do is to use the same text box over and over for different inputs as the website guides the user to do different tasks (which all functions are written in js)

I'm trying to figure out a way to use this same text box for all inputs users have to insert, but so far nothing is working.

I tried creating a function like:

```
function enter_value(){
  var name = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
}
```

This should be able to store the value of the input in the variable name. Problem is, I want to execute this when button is pressed, but the button is not responding and the variable "name" always returns "Enter Your Input Here" (is this default?)

What am I missing here?

Comment: I just added your html and js to the page (with a `console.log(name)` at the end of your function) and it is logging the correct text.  I have a feeling you are having an issue with scope, where are you trying to use the name variable?

Comment: You can only have one instance of an "id" in your DOM.

Comment: Not sure I fully follow what your trying to do. But as is your name variable is scoped to enter_value so can not be accessed from outside of it. The most direct, but dirtiest, approach is to use a global name variable instead. However global variables are bad so what you may actually want to do is build an object to wrap all your functionality and variables in.

Comment: When I tested the code using things like document.write, the variable does have a value, so I guess my question is more about how to "repeatedly" use this box for inputs

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried so far? We need something to start with so we have a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @javaauthority Do you know another way to achieve my goal? I want to know how to be able to use one single text box and read the different inputs every time the user types something in

Comment: @wolffer-east I don't have lot done yet. I'm pretty much stuck on this part. What I put on is pretty much what I have, along with some other functions that don't really relate to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely re use the same text box to take in more than one piece of information. The question is how do you store the info in the process. So you can keep the onclick handler that you already have, then change what you do with the input based on the state of the page.

```
Current Step: <div id="current_step">name</div>

<input type="text" id="myInput" style="height: 10px; width: 50px" value="">
<button onclick="enter_value()">Confirm</button>

<div class="results">
  <div id="name_result"></div>
  <div id="addr_result"></div>
</div>
function enter_value(){
  var curStep = document.getElementById("current_step").innerHTML,
      curValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  //do some error testing here, if it is a bad submission dont continue
  if (curValue == "") return false;
  if (curStep == "name"){
    document.getElementById("name_result").innerHTML = curValue
    document.getElementById("current_step").innerHTML = "address"
  }
  else if (curStep == "address"){
    document.getElementById("addr_result").innerHTML = curValue
    document.getElementById("current_step").innerHTML = "Done!"
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = '';
}
```

You should be able to use this to get started

Comment: Thanx just I can definetely use this in future projects

Comment: I'll do more research into this one, but I think this will help tremendously. I'll just tag this as solved. Thanks a lot!